# Missing doc in aggregated results and wrong count of items

Tags: elasticsearch

I have such data in ES:

```
{"action":"B1", "status":"E", "name": "abc", "version":0, "colour": "red"}
{"action":"B1", "status":"E", "name": "def", "version":1, "colour": "red"}
{"action":"B1", "status":"E", "name": "was", "version":2, "colour": "red"}
{"action":"B2", "status":"V", "name": "acc", "version":0, "colour": "red"}
{"action":"B3", "status":"E", "name": "fff", "version":0, "colour": "red"}
{"action":"B3", "status":"V", "name": "ttt", "version":1, "colour": "red"}
{"action":"B4", "status":"V", "name": "ttt", "version":1, "colour": "blue"}
```

**The requirements are:**

- Take only items with colour = red

And for all red items I need to do some grouping by action name and for each action name group:

- if there are multiple actions in is in E state, take the item with latest version and add it to results
- if there are actions is in V state, add all of them to results

**Correct results would be (sorted by name ASC):**

```
 {"action":"B2", "status":"V", "name": "acc", "version"=0} //this was returned because all actions with status V should be returned
 {"action":"B3", "status":"E", "name": "fff", "version"=0} //there were two actions in B3 group, it returned the one with highest version and E state
 {"action":"B3", "status":"V", "name": "ttt", "version"=1} //there were two actions in B3 group, it returned the one with V state, because they should be always added to results
 {"action":"B1", "status":"E", "name": "was", "version"=2} //there were many actions in B1 group so it returned the one with highest version
```

I want to search documents. And my query looks like this:

```
 GET  myIndex/_search
 {   
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "red",
            "fields": [
              "colour"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  } ,
  "version": true,
  "explain": false,
  
  "aggregations": {
    "all_items": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "action",
        "size": 10, //I AM NOT SURE WHAT THIS SIZE SPECIFIES ? I want first page of 10 elements
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": [
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "bbb": {
          "top_hits": {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 1,
            "version": false,
            "seq_no_primary_term": false,
            "explain": false,
            "fields": [
              {
                "field": "version"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**My current results are wrong. Problems:**

**1)**

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 6,
      "relation" : "eq"
    }
```

`hits.hits` the totalHits=6 is greater than number of documents in buckets (3) and I cannot construct paging information (in my pager I should see total number of elements which should be 4)

```
{"action":"B1", "status":"E", "name": "abc", "version"=0, "colour" = red}
{"action":"B1", "status":"E", "name": "def", "version"=1, "colour" = red}
{"action":"B1", "status":"E", "name": "was", "version"=2, "colour" = red}
{"action":"B2", "status":"V", "name": "acc", "version"=0, "colour" = red}
{"action":"B3", "status":"E", "name": "fff", "version"=0, "colour" = red}
{"action":"B3", "status":"V", "name": "ttt", "version"=1, "colour" = red}
```

**2)** In result buckets I have documents grouped by statuses:

**bucket with key B1** //OK

- hits.total.value=3
- hits:
  `{"action":"B1", "status":"E", "name": "was", "version"=2, "colour" = red}`

**bucket with key B2** //OK

- hits.total.value=1
- hits:
  `{"action":"B2", "status":"V", "name": "acc", "version"=0, "colour" = red}`

**bucket with key B3** //WRONG

- hits.total.value=2
- hits:
  `{"action":"B3", "status":"V", "name": "ttt", "version"=1, "colour" = red}`

**So here I am missing this document:**
`{"action":"B3", "status":"E", "name": "fff", "version"=0, "colour" = red}`
because aggregation took the document with highest version from this bucket. But according to requirements I should take all elements with V status and the last item (in terms of version) with E status.

Any help would be appreciated.

As for loosing elements with status V I have some idea, for example to introduce new field for grouping (so that I would not group by action field but by newGroupingDiscriminatorField) and assign to such field respect value:

- when status is E the value is action name, like B1
- when status is V the value would be random uuid, so they each such item would be in results in separate bucket and would not be lost. Is it good idea or there is something that ES offers and could be used ?

I don't have idea for correct totalCount (i should show to the user that he is watching 1-10 element from 120 of them -> 120 means 120 elements ready to display, already grouped with eliminated unneccessary items, not before grouping)

I don't know which part of the query would be responsible for getting only first page from all grouped elelements. First page has 10 elements. But to get first page only I need to group all documents first right.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer #1. Document Extraction

You can solve it by `scripted_metric`

Your documents

```
PUT /complex_selection/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"action":"B1", "status":"E", "name": "was", "version": 2, "colour": "red"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"action":"B1", "status":"E", "name": "abc", "version": 0, "colour": "red"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"action":"B1", "status":"E", "name": "def", "version": 1, "colour": "red"}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"action":"B2", "status":"V", "name": "acc", "version": 0, "colour": "red"}
{"create":{"_id":5}}
{"action":"B3", "status":"E", "name": "fff", "version": 0, "colour": "red"}
{"create":{"_id":6}}
{"action":"B3", "status":"V", "name": "ttt", "version": 1, "colour": "red"}
{"create":{"_id":7}}
{"action":"B4", "status":"V", "name": "ttt", "version": 1, "colour": "blue"}
```

Scripted metric query

```
POST /complex_selection/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "colour": {
                "value": "red"
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "selected_documents": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script": "state.actions = [:];",
                "map_script": """
                    def action = params['_source']['action'];
                    def status = params['_source']['status'];
                    def document = params['_source'];
                    
                    if (state.actions[action] == null) {
                        state.actions[action] = [:];
                    }

                    if (state.actions[action][status] == null) {
                            state.actions[action][status] = [];
                    }

                    if (status == 'E') {
                        if (state.actions[action][status].size() > 0) {
                            def mapDocumentVersion = state.actions[action][status][0]['version'];
                            def documentVersion = document['version'];
                            if (mapDocumentVersion >= documentVersion) {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        state.actions[action][status] = [];
                    }
                    
                    state.actions[action][status].add(document);
                """,
                "combine_script": "return state.actions",
                "reduce_script": """
                    Map selectedDocuments = new HashMap();
                    for (state in states) {
                        selectedDocuments.putAll(state);
                    }
                    
                    List documents = [];
                    Set mapActions = selectedDocuments.keySet();
                    for (mapAction in mapActions) {
                        Set mapStatuses = selectedDocuments[mapAction].keySet();
                        for (mapStatus in mapStatuses) {
                            List value = selectedDocuments[mapAction][mapStatus];
                            documents.addAll(value);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    return documents;
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "selected_documents" : {
            "value" : [
                {
                    "colour" : "red",
                    "name" : "acc",
                    "action" : "B2",
                    "version" : 0,
                    "status" : "V"
                },
                {
                    "colour" : "red",
                    "name" : "fff",
                    "action" : "B3",
                    "version" : 0,
                    "status" : "E"
                },
                {
                    "colour" : "red",
                    "name" : "ttt",
                    "action" : "B3",
                    "version" : 1,
                    "status" : "V"
                },
                {
                    "colour" : "red",
                    "name" : "was",
                    "action" : "B1",
                    "version" : 2,
                    "status" : "E"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE!** This query is for one-shard indices. The reduce_script stage code is simplified and not correct for many-shard indices

Comment: But what about totalElements and paging ?

Comment: @SereneAtk, modify the `reduce_script` stage code. `documents` is a list with methods for extracting a sublist (method `sublist`) and a length (method `size`). Your question was very interesting

Comment: How much of this script is important for paging+totalElements and how much for grouping ? I wonder about efficiency. Instead of calculating group last element using script I now index new field groupDiscriminator = action (if status = E) and = UUID when status is V (to get all V items) and it seems to me that it would be faster to aggregate items by this groupDiscriminator than any script solution. I don't know what about totalElements/paging how to get totalElements in my approach.. Maybe it is not possible in my approach ?

Comment: When I just remove path from your query I still see total value = 6 instead of 4. So how would I know how many total elements to see is out there ? When I would index 150k red elements and 100k would be the real final count for aggregated results, I would need that information, I would need 10 returned documents and the info that there is 100k hits in total instead of 150k.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer #2. Q & A

I answer your comment questions in this message

> How much of this script is important for paging+totalElements and how
> much for grouping ?

This script is important for grouping only (see the response). For paging+totalElements you need to post-process the `documents` variable. `documents` is java.util.List (see my comment)

> Maybe it is not possible in my approach?

My approach isn't the one. Maybe your approach is right. Or maybe you need re-organize your data. I think of it, but don't know how. Or maybe you need post-process data outside Elasticsearch

> When I just remove path from your query I still see total value = 6
> instead of 4. So how would I know how many total elements to see is
> out there ?

There are two parts in a response. The first one is hits. My scripted metric query isn't filter hits. The second one is a script result. If you need hits, then see hits (6). If you need the script result, then see the script result (4)

> When I would index 150k red elements and 100k would be the real final
> count for aggregated results, I would need that information, I would
> need 10 returned documents and the info that there is 100k hits in
> total instead of 150k.

Sorry, I have no time to write the final script and test it. I show an approach to solve your problem. Does my script group your data? Yes. Can you use it for paging+totalElements? Yes. Is my script real time? No. Can my script process 150k documents? Test it

Comment: Thanks, I have one more question. Would the script approach need to take all grouped data to see proper total amount of grouped elements?

Comment: @SereneAtk, yes, the script approach would need to take all grouped data to see proper total amount of grouped elements. You can don't store documents with `"status" : "V"`, but count of such documents

Answer (score 0):

## Answer #3. Document counting

I've modified a script for you to count totalElements. The script stores only the status E documents. The status V documents are only counted. **NOTE!** It's still the script for one-shard index

```
POST /complex_selection/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
        "query": {
                "term": {
                        "colour": {
                                "value": "red"
                        }
                }
        },
        "aggs": {
                "selected_documents": {
                        "scripted_metric": {
                                "init_script": """
                                    state.actions = [:];
                                    state.actions['V'] = 0;
                                """,
                                "map_script": """
                                    def action = params['_source']['action'];
                                    def status = params['_source']['status'];
                                    def document = params['_source'];

                                    if (state.actions[status] == null) {
                                        state.actions[status] = [:];
                                    }

                                    if (status == 'E') {
                                        if (state.actions[status][action] != null) {
                                            def mapDocumentVersion = state.actions[status][action]['version'];
                                            def documentVersion = document['version'];
                                            if (mapDocumentVersion >= documentVersion) {
                                                return;
                                            }
                                        } 
                                        state.actions[status][action] = document;
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    if (status == 'V') {
                                        state.actions[status]++;
                                    }
                                """,
                                "combine_script": "return state.actions",
                                "reduce_script": """
                                    Map selectedDocuments = new HashMap();
                                    for (state in states) {
                                        selectedDocuments.putAll(state);
                                    }

                                    List documents = new LinkedList();
                                    Set mapStatuses = selectedDocuments.keySet();
                                    for (mapStatus in mapStatuses) {
                                        if (mapStatus != 'V') {
                                            Set mapActions = selectedDocuments[mapStatus].keySet();
                                            for (mapAction in mapActions) {
                                                String value = selectedDocuments[mapStatus][mapAction].value;
                                                documents.add(value);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                    int documentEStatusCount = documents.size();
                                    int documentVStatusCount = selectedDocuments['V'];
                                        
                                    return documentEStatusCount + documentVStatusCount;
                                """
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "selected_documents" : {
            "value" : 4
        }
    }
}
```